# How to test a component for a button click that has a function passed to it as props from the parent component

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mount, enzyme

I have a parent component that keeps all the state and that renders my child component inside a Router. I'm passing a function from parent to child as props to handle the button click.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import arrayOfObjects from '../arrayOfObjects';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

class Parent extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.fetchObject = this.fetchObject.bind(this);

        const tempmyObject = {};
        this.state = {
            myObject: tempmyObject           
        };
    }

      fetchObject(event) {
        const that = this;
        fetch(path)
            ....
            that.setState(
            {
               myObject: newObject      
            });
            ....
        event.preventDefault();
    };

      render() {
         return (
            <Router>
                <div>          

                    <Route exact path='/GetUserInfo'
                           render={(props) => (
                               <ChildComponent {...props}
                                             fields={arrayOfObjects}
                                             myObject={this.state.myObject}
                                             onChange={(event) => this.fetchObject(event)}
                                             buttonName='foo'
                               />
                           )}

                    />

                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
export default Parent ;
```

---

```
import ShowChildComponent from './ShowChildComponent';
class ChildComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ShowChildComponent
                    fields={this.props.arrayOfObjects}
                    myObject={this.state.myObject}
                    buttonName={this.props.name}
                    onChange={this.props.onChange}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

I'm using mount from enzyme and I would like to test it and simulate a button click in my unit tests, and then test for the changed data in the paragraph.

Previous to that, I had all state kept in the child component like this :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import ShowChildComponent from './ShowChildComponent';

class ChildComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
        const tempmyObject = {};

        this.state = {
            myObject: tempmyObject
        };
    }

    fetchData(event) {
        const that = this;
        fetch(this.props.path)
            .....
            that.setState(
                {
                    myObject: myObject,
                });
            ....
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ShowChildComponent
                    fields={this.props.arrayOfObjects}
                    myObject={this.state.myObject}
                    buttonName={this.props.name}
                    onChange={this.fetchData}
                />
            </div>
        );
        }
    }
    export default ChildComponent;
```

and I could simulate a click. My tests looked like this:

```
it('renders ChildComponent button click message', () => {
            const wrapper = mount(<ChildComponent fields={arrayOfObjects}
                                                  myObject={myObject}
                                                  path={'/some/path'}
                                                  buttonName='foo'
            />);
            const p = <p className='myParagraph' id={id}>{value}</p>;
            wrapper.find('button.getData').simulate('click');
            expect(wrapper.find(ShowChildComponent).containsMatchingElement(p)).toEqual(true);
        });
```

How do I achieve the same thing after I refactored?

Comment: Show the code, please.

Comment: I don't think it's very unit test-y to test that the actual function is called when you click on the child component - that function lives in the parent component. Instead I'd have two tests - one that checks that this function is passed to the child, and one that checks that a function stub that is passed to the child is called on click.